# Update Spyder IDE without Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I have installed the spyder IDE version 3 using the commands from the following [link](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html) on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to update it from version 3 to version 4 but couldn't find any way to do it.
I have installed it separately despite having anaconda installed on my system due to some requirements and dependencies which I might break if I do it that way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install spyder`?

Comment: it should be pip install spyder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Although you don't mention it clearly, it seems you're trying to install Spyder 4 using `apt-get`. If that's the case, you need to be aware that Spyder 4 is not part of Ubuntu 20.04, as can be seen [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/spyder).